# Randomize columns in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Quiz options data in 4 columns and 100 rows of excel like this:

```
A B C D    
A B C D    
A B C D    
A B C D
```

I want to randomize it as :

```
B C D A (random order of values in columns)    
A C B D    
D B C A    
D C A B
```

A B C D are multiple choice answer options to any question and they represent string.

I will upload this excel in a PHP quiz application, currently option A is right answer for each question and I want to shuffle options.

How would I go about this? Can I use the `rand()` function, and if so, how?

Comment: My first thought is four helper columns with a lookup based on rank, but there could be other ways.  What have you tried?

Comment: Using rand() will cause the order of the choices to be randomized every time the sheet is calculated. If you are expecting a more consistent, but a bit less predictable, try custom `MOD` function

Comment: How do you expect to use this? How the students will work on the quiz? Do they work on the excel on computer, or printed? I assume you want each student options is ordered randomly, right?

Comment: How does my answer below work/not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

How does this work? I tweaked a formula found [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/10/12/sort-a-list-in-random-order-in-excel/)

Assuming your data is in A:D, put this in F1 and drag over and down:

`=INDEX($A$1:$D$1, LARGE((COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)-MIN(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1))+1)*(COUNTIF($E1:E1, $A$1:$D$1)<>COUNTIF($A$1:$D$1, $A$1:$D$1)), RANDBETWEEN(1, SUM(--(COUNTIF($E1:E1, $A$1:$D$1)<>COUNTIF($A$1:$D$1, $A$1:$D$1))))))`

Note: Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> as it's an array formula.

[image]